# Php function to format, prettify css

Tags: php, css, development-environment

Is there any php functions you know of that will prettify/format inline css on the fly?

I have php functions that will do the opposite and minify css, js, html from https://gist.github.com/tovic/d7b310dea3b33e4732c0

I'm looking for something that will do the opposite for at least, css, hopefully js too.

I'm using this minify function in my theme I'm building, but I want to offer developers the option to load non-minified styles and scripts for testing and developing. This already works for me by just loading the .css files instead of the .min.css files. But, for some of the inline styles this doesn't work. I would like the inline (echo) styles to be prettified as well, when developers choose to load the prettified files. This would be great!

Do you know of any?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you make it pretty as you write it?

Comment: Hi. I've done that already, as I said. But there are "some" inline styles that are generated dynamically from other resources (ie: wordpress plugins) and when I run developer mode and load the prettified styles, some styles are still a bit minified from those resources. While I can run their dynamic styles through my function and minify their styles, I can't prettify those dynamic styles without editing their plugin. So it would be nice to find a function like this so I can offer a seamless experiences when in developer mode.

Comment: Everything is possibly with PHP. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @DJones thanks and that's good to know! Appreciate it!